# Package android app with editable resources

Tags: android, storage, internal

I wish to package my application with some text files that the application can later edit. These are small, private files that I don't want to share with other apps, so as far as I understand, I am to use internal storage.

In Android Studio, where do I put these files so that they are accessible with openFileInput()? Or do I have to put the files in the assets folder and copy them to internal storage at runtime?

Comment: Text files are, by definition, composed by strings. So, you could provide them as fields in a database. And they can still be edited and later reshown updated.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a bit of an overkill, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: It's no more overkill than opening, editing and saving - then reloading text files... ;)